# submit form button is not firing

Tags: angular, devextreme-angular

I have a devextreme form with some fields and a submit button on it. If I hit the submit button, the corresponding click event in the component isn't firing. The `useSubmitBehavior` is set to true and the `submit` event is set to the component click event. Here is a simple example: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxpopup-fn7b1f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to put your `<dx-form>` tag inside `<form>` and move `(submit)="formSubmit()"` to`<form>` tag

```
<form (submit)="formSubmit()">
  <dx-form>
    <dxi-item dataField="name">
      <dxi-validation-rule type="async" message="name already exists" 
       [validationCallback]="alreadyExists">
      </dxi-validation-rule>
    </dxi-item>
    <dxi-item>
      <dx-button text="submit" [useSubmitBehavior]="true"></dx-button>
      <dx-button text="close" (click)="closeButtonClick()"></dx-button>
    </dxi-item>
  </dx-form>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. I thought, the dxForm implements the stadard form functionality and that I don't need to wrap it in a form tag.